# Explicit form of this unitary transformation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-physics

**Disclaimer:** This question has its motivation from physics. It is probably not entirely rigorous at the moment. I just want to clarify some steps and try to make the arguments rigorous afterwards, if possible.

The following was extracted from page 66 of [Statistical Field Theory](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/statistical-field-theory/12165C27CD62CD75E6DE2BD39CE42859). Suppose we have families of fermionic creation and annihilation operators $\{a_{x}^{*}\}_{x\in \mathbb{Z}}$ and $\{a_{x}\}_{x\in \mathbb{Z}}$, respectively. These satisfy anticommutation relations $\{a_{x}^{*},a_{y}^{*}\} = \{a_{x},a_{y}\} = 0$ and $\{a_{x},a_{y}^{*}\} = \delta_{xy}$, where the latter is just the Kronecker delta. In the mentioned book, the authors introduce a unitary operator $U$ which is defined by its action, as follows:
$$U^{-1}a_{x}^{*}U = \frac{1}{2}i(a_{x+1}^{*}-a_{x}^{*}+a_{x+1}+a_{x}) \tag{1}\label{1}$$
$$U^{-1}a_{x}U = \frac{1}{2}i(-a_{x+1}^{*}-a_{x}^{*}-a_{x+1}+a_{x}) \tag{2}\label{2}.$$
This operator $U$ is never made explicit, and it is difficult for me to understand what is going on. My question is: can someone please help me understand what is being done in the above formulas? It *seems* that these are some sort of Bogoliubov transformations, but I am not quite sure. Most importantly: can we write these operators explicitly, as exponential maps? For example, is there a realization $U = e^{Q}$, where $Q$ is a self-adjoint quadratic form on the creation and annihilation operators, from which $e^{-Q}a_{x}^{\#}e^{Q}$ reproduces (\ref{1}) and (\ref{2})?

**Add:** To make it more clear, I am not very interested about existence of the operator $U$ itself; I strongly believe such an operator exists. The point is to write it explicitly, in such a way that (\ref{1}) and (\ref{2}) can be obtained.

Comment: You could apply a fourier transform, i.e. you could consider the problem in momentum space. If you impose periodic boundary conditions, then the calculations a rigorous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me define (for $x\in\mathbb{Z}$) the Hermitian operators
$$\gamma_{2x-1}=a_x+a_x^\dagger,\;\;\gamma_{2x}=i(a_x-a_x^\dagger).$$
The $\gamma_n$'s are known in physics as [Majorana operators.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorana_fermion) Each fermion operator $a_x$ is mapped onto a pair of Majorana operators $\gamma_{2x-1}$ and $\gamma_{2x}$. Notice that $\gamma_n\gamma_m=-\gamma_m\gamma_n$ for $n\neq m$, while $\gamma_n^2=1$. This implies that $2^{-1/2}(\gamma_n+\gamma_m)$ is unitary for $n\neq m$.

I seek a unitary operator $U$ which translates $\gamma_n$ to $\gamma_{n+1}$:
$$U\gamma_{2x-1}U^{-1}=\gamma_{2x},\;\;U\gamma_{2x}U^{-1}=\gamma_{2x+1}.$$
This is equivalent to the transformation in the OP,
$$Ua_xU^{-1}=\tfrac{1}{2}U\bigl(\gamma_{2x-1}-i\gamma_{2x}\bigr)U^{-1}=\tfrac{1}{2}\bigl(\gamma_{2x}-i\gamma_{2x+1}\bigr)=\tfrac{1}{2}i(a_x-a_x^\dagger-a_{x+1}-a_{x+1}^\dagger).$$

I place the Majorana operators $\gamma_n$ on a ring, taking $n\in\{1,2,\ldots 2N\}$ and identifying $\gamma_{2N+1}\equiv \gamma_1$. Then the desired translation operator is given by the unitary operator product
$$U=2^{1/2-N}(\gamma_1+\gamma_2)(\gamma_2+\gamma_3)\cdots(\gamma_{2N-1}+\gamma_{2N}).$$

Comment: Carlo, thanks for the comments. I am trying to figure this out for a long time now and I ran out of ideas. I simply cannot understand what they are doing (even in the linked article, which I also consulted a couple times but it did not help me).

Comment: I have worked it out, it's actually a rather simple expression.

Comment: Carlo, thanks for the answer now! I skimmed over it and seems that I follow your reasoning. I am going to work out the details later, but I am already accepting your answer. Related: do you think $U$ can be written in an exponential form as well? I will try to figure it out later too.

Comment: exponential form: not entirely; take $N=1$, then $2^{-1/2}(\gamma_1+\gamma_2)=\gamma_1 e^{(\pi/4)\gamma_1\gamma_2}$, but I don't think you can absorb the first $\gamma_1$ into the exponent.

Answer (score 6):

Denote by $b_x^*$ and $b_x$ the right-hand sides of (1) and (2). They satisfy the anticommutation relations, and therefore there is an isomorphism from the $C^*$-algebra generated by the $a_x$'s onto the $C^*$-algebra generated by the $b_x$'s sending $a_x$ to $b_x$.

However, this isomorphism is not implemented by a unitary. That is, there is no unitary transformation of the antisymmetric Fock space that satisfies your relations.

Indeed, if such a $U$ existed, then evaluating (2) at the vacuum state would give that
$$ \| a_x (U\Omega)\| = \frac{1}{2}\| U (a_{x+1}^* + a_x^* + a_{x+1} -a_x)\Omega\| = \frac{1}{2}\| a_{x+1}^* \Omega + a_x^* \Omega\| = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}.$$
The contradiction comes from the fact that for every vector $\xi$ in the antisymmetric Fock space, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \|a_x \xi\| = 0$ ($\|a_x \xi\| = 0$ if $x$ does not appear anywhere in $\xi$).

Two remarks:

- I am not even sure that the $C^*$-algebra generated by the $b_x$'s is not a strict subalgebra of the $C^*$-algebra generated by the $a_x$'s. This would give another, even stronger, reason why $U$ does not exist.
- As mentionned in the comments, what you claim becomes true if you replace $\mathbf{Z}$ by $\mathbf{Z}/N\mathbf{Z}$. Indeed, in that case, comparing the dimensions we see that $C^*( (b_x)_x) = C^*((a_x)_x) \simeq M_{2^N}$, and since automorphisms of $M_{2^N}$ are inner you get such a unitary $U$.

Comment: Mikael, thanks for the answer. As I said, the problem as it is is still a bit imprecise in its formulation. I chose to index the operators by $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ because I thought the boundary conditions would not play any role; the authors themselves say that the transformations (\ref{1}) and (\ref{2}) assume implicitly a thermodynamic limit. Maybe the correct approach is in fact to consider $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ instead. In this case, can a explicit realization for $U$ and $U^{-1}$ be obtained?

Comment: I would be happy to have an explicit formula for $U$ and $U^{-1}$ which would justify (\ref{1}) and (\ref{2}).